# Setting a CMFCPropertySheet as RTL

Tags: mfc, right-to-left, propertysheet

I have seen several similar question on this subject but I can seem to resolve it.

For example, on CodeProject:

https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2873837/Re-How-to-set-RTL-layout-for-a-CPropertySheet.aspx

And on SO:

[RTL layout issue for Property Sheets (MFC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719153/rtl-layout-issue-for-property-sheets-mfc)

So, I have a `CMFCPropertySheet` that is my main application window and it is set to Arabic when the program starts:

[image: Arabic window]

The problem, as it the case for other users, is that whilst the pages are correctly set to RTL layout the **sheet** is not.

What is the correct way to get the sheet itself to display RTL?

I tried to use `PreCreateWindow` and it made no difference. I tried to use `SetProcessDefaultLayout` too. No joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the window style should be changed in `OnNcCreate` before the window starts creating and positioning its child controls. This way, the child tab, as well as child buttons, will be positioned accordingly (OK/Cancel/Apply button will be aligned to the left side as well).

Example:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(...)
    ON_WM_NCCREATE()
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMyPropertySheet::OnNcCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT pc)
{
    BOOL res = CMFCPropertySheet::OnNcCreate(pc);

    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,
            WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE));

    return res;
}
```

Alternatively, do this in `OnInitDialog`, use `::FindWindowEx(m_hWnd, 0, WC_TABCONTROL, 0)` to find tab control's handle and change its style. This way the buttons are not re-positioned. Example:

```
BOOL CMyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CMFCPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();

    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,
        WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE));

    HWND htabctrl = ::FindWindowEx(m_hWnd, 0, WC_TABCONTROL, 0);
    SetWindowLongPtr(htabctrl, GWL_EXSTYLE,
        WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | GetWindowLongPtr(htabctrl, GWL_EXSTYLE));

    return res;
}
```

---

*Side note:*

You can also call `SetProcessDefaultLayout(LAYOUT_RTL)` at the start of the process (for example in `CMyWinApp::InitInstance`). Then change the layout depending on the result from `GetProcessDefaultLayout`. So you remember not to accidentally change the style for the Latin version...

Comment: For  SetProcessDefaultLayout I understand I need to link user32.lib, and include windows.h and winuser.h.

Comment: When would you call SetProcessDefaultLayout? When language resources are loaded?

Comment: I think I made this unnecessarily complicated by talking about `SetProcessDefaultLayout`. You don't need that at all. See edit...